# rename refactor in eclipse

Tags: java, refactoring, rename, eclipse-plugin

While developing Eclispe plugin, I am able to programmatically rename a class-field using the following code.

```
RenameSupport renameSupport = RenameSupport.create(field, newName, RenameSupport.UPDATE_REFERENCES);
renameSupport.perform(workbench.getShell(), workbench);
```

But it applies the changes to the actual source files. Is there anyway that can be prevented? I just need the renamed code internally (for performing some other computations), must not change the actual source.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You could copy it into a temporary file with  [`File.createTempFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%29)  and then rename the code in your temporary file, if `RenameSupport` lets you do that.  If it doesn't, then you can copy the original to a temporary file and copy it back once your other computations are finished.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's the last option I would avail. I am wondering if there is any API support/workaround, that I may not know.

Answer (score 0):

First, create an instance of `RefactoringDescriptor`. Then, invoke `createRefactoring` on it to create an instance of `Refactoring`. You can get the change object by invoking `createChange` on the `Refactoring` object. The `Change` object will tell you how the refactoring is going to change the code. Finally, you can invoke the method `perform` on the `Change` object to apply it on the underlying files.

The plugin `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests.refactoring` contains automated unit tests for Java refactorings in Eclipse. For a concrete example of how to invoke a refactoring programmatically, refer to [org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests.refactoring.RefactoringTest](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests.refactoring/test%20cases/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/tests/refactoring/RefactoringTest.java?view=markup).